# Java EE application and "global" variables

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, global-variables

we have a Java EE application with primefaces and we are wondering if there's a way to have a "global" application variable.

I mean: imagine user1 is editing document1, when user2 try to access document1 we'd like to show a message: "User1 is already editing this document".

So, we have to use something "global" for keep track of user action or document locking and so on, what's the best way to achieve this?

I've search the internet but opinion differs and generally no working examples are provided, so link and pointer are welcome!

EDIT: the above is just an example, please not focus on "documents", you can call it "resources", or whatever you like. I've used the document lock problem as an example, but it can be a total counter or something else that need to be stores at application level. 
What I'm asking (and sorry if it was not clear) is not how to manage document locking, but what's the best way to have a "global" variable at application level in Java EE, if it's possible.

Thank you

Just curious: why if I add "hola," or "hi," as first line it disappear when I save the edit?

Comment: How do you maintain the documents ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you please add details?

Comment: I mean do you use CMS, database or something else ? how do you manage the documents ? If CMS then I guess you have options to lock and check the status of the document.

Comment: It'a an application in Java EE, nothing to do with CMS or similar.

Comment: The way you store the document is important and could affect your locking strategy. As could requirements on whether your app is distributable and how you want the locking to work. Without more information you're unlikely to get a good answer.

Comment: Ok, I will add details, anyway: I'm not focusing on "documents", I can call it "resources", or whatever. What I'm asking really is not how to manage document locking, but what's the best way to have a "global" variable at application level in Java EE, if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save something globally, in Java EE 6+ it should use the **Application Scope**

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html

For example:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class Global {
   void setDocInUse(boolean) { ... }
   boolean isDocInUse() { ... }
}

@RequestScoped
class MyDocEditor {

    @Inject Global global;

    public void edit() {
       if (global.isDocInUse()) { ... }
       else  { ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that this solution does not work accross a cluster out of the box. Is it?

Comment: No, @ApplicationScoped is not shared between members of the cluster. If you want a global clustered value, it's a different story

Answer (score -1):

For most simple cases you can use a static field inside your managed beans for that purpose because it will be shared by all the instances of your managed bean. For example, let us imagine that to edit documents you users interact with the following bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped    
public class DocumentManager {
    private static Map<Long, String> editedDocs = new HashMap<>();
    private Document selectedDoc;

}
```

Then let us imagine that after users have selected the document (for example from the dataTable so that it gets into the selectedDoc field) they get the document editing page by clicking on a button which action attribute points to the method editDocument like this:

then in your editDocument method we add the document's id and username of the user that clicked on the button to the mapping that tracks presently edited documents.

```
public String editDocument() {
    if (!editedDocs.contains(selectedDoc.getId())) {
         String username = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal().getName();
         editedDocs.put(selectedDoc.getId(), username);    

         String msg = "User " + username + " is already editing the document";
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, msg));
    }
    return theAddressOfEditDocumentPage;
}
```

Please do not forget to delete the document id and the username from the editedDocs when the user leaves the edit page (by clicking Save or Cancel buttons). 
Another possibility is to store such mapping externally (e.g. in the database)

Comment: This solution is not thread safe and also will not work in a clustered environment

Comment: the code i have provided is meant to illustrate the idea of how it could be done, its not a bull blown ready-for-use code. If your remember I also purposed to  store the mapping externally which will work in a clustered environment. So it find your downvote pointless.

Comment: Also by the way I don't remember the OP mentioning that he uses a cluster.